# Mott's conjecture about NiO verified or not?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Mott in his 1949 paper, said:

''On the view explained above, therefore, if a substance such as NiO were subjected to very high pressure it should suddenly show metallic conduction for some value of the pressure, and the effective number of free electrons would suddenly jump to about one per atom''

Is this conjecture verified by experiment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are in luck.  Alexander Gavriliuk, Ivan Trojan, and Viktor Struzhkin observed the anticipated transition in 2012.  Their paper is in Physical Review Letters  109 086402 (2012) ([link to the paper](http://journals.aps.org/prl/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevLett.109.086402)).  They mention Mott's prediction in the abstract, and discuss the various prediction of where it would occur in comparison to what they observed. Now, they had to go up to 240GPa to see it, but...